# How to cancel a pjax event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, pjax, event-propagation

I am using pjax in this way (from https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax):

> Two. Slightly obtrusive, passing a container and binding an error
>   handler:

```
<a href='/explore' class='js-pjax'>Explore</a>

$('#main').pjax('.js-pjax').on('pjax:error', function(e, xhr, err) {
  $('.error').text('Something went wrong: ' + err)
})
```

In some cases, my link may have a class that should prevent the link from going through `<a href='/explore' class='js-pjax no-link'>Explore</a>`

And the code to stop it:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.no-link', function() {
    return false;
});
```

My problem is: in this scenario, return false/preventDefault does not stop the pjax from firing.

Any suggestions how to stop the pjax if the 'js-pjax' link also hasClass('no-link')?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent PJAX from following `.no-link` elements by modifying your initial PJAX call.

```
$('#main').pjax('.js-pjax:not(.no-link)').on('pjax:error', function(e, xhr, err) {
    $('.error').text('Something went wrong: ' + err)
})
```